# Enterprise Architect Document Generator creates report with inconsistent headings

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a question regarding the creation of documents in Enterprise Architect v14.0.1423.

When I create documents via the standard "Model Report" (regardless if with or without TOC and/or Style Sheet) I end up with headings not following my package structure: the 1st element in the 9th package ends up as a level 1 heading (same as the previous 9 packages). The behaviour is only observed when I select the option `Skip root package`.

`Stakeholder Type 1` is incorrectly formatted as `Heading 1` as chapter 10 instead of `Heading 2` as chapter 9.2 (see figures below). In addition, it does not matter if have included the diagram or not.

My question is: do I have to use a different model report template when creating documents when I want to skip the root package? (If this is a bug, I will certainly open a bug report with Sparx.)

**Below you find the package and element structure:**

[image: Package Structure 1/2]

[image: Package Structure 2/2]

**These are the option used for generating the document:**

[image: Document Generator Option 1/2]

[image: Document Generator Option 2/2]

**This is the TOC of the generated document:**

[image: Table of Contents with wrong heading structure]

Comment: Quite possible that this is a bug, but it can also depend on which template is used. The option "Adjust Heading Levels" is supposed to control that behavior I think.

Comment: regarding "Adjust Heading Levels": According to the documentation and my tests this option only controls the maximum depth headings are being generated. I now open a bug report at Sparx which is filed under #18120944.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confirmed to be a bug by Sparx which is filed under id #18120944. The problem also exists for version 14.1.1427.